How to stream integrated camera to Facebook using FFMpeg
I'm currently using this command to stream to Facebook:
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="HD User Facing":audio="Varios micrófonos (Realtek(R) Audio)" -c:v h264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 -g 60 -b:v 2500k -bufsize 5000k -maxrate 3000k -preset veryfast -tune zerolatency -f flv "rtmps://live-api-s.facebook.com:443/rtmp/key"

It works fine on YouTube, but I'm struggling to get it to work on Facebook. I'm not receiving any signal. Any ideas on what might be wrong or how to fix it?"

Do you pass along the RTMPS key anywhere? How does this command differ from the one you're using to stream to YT? What does FBs documentation say about this process? What other commands have you tried? Please EDIT your question and add this and other relevant information to the question itself, particularly focusing on the research you've done/info you've learned, and what you've tried.
